# What is the purpose of dreams?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, dream

What is the purpose of dreams? I understand there are different types of dreams. I also understand that either directly or indirectly they are from our Creator. But, what is their purpose?
Please give sources if you are able.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Asalaam Alaikum

purpose of dreams can be very general in meaning but i will try to clarify more based on authentic sunnah and quran, insha Allah.

first let us look at the hadith that lays the foundation for everything about dreams.

**"True dreams are one of the forty-six parts of Prophethood." (al-Bukhaari, 6472; Muslim, 4201)**

and now to have a better understanding of the purpose of dreams, let us remind ourselves of this following hadith.

**"That will be because the Prophethood and its effects will be so far away in time, so the believers will be given some compensation in the form of dreams which will bring them some good news or will help them to be patient and steadfast in their faith." (al-Bukhaari, 6499; Muslim, 4200)**

from this hadith it is very clear to us about the purpose dreams. it is something that will bring good news to believers and help them to be firm in their faith. as you have mentioned that you understand the different types of dreams, i find no reason to address that here.

i would like to remind you and me about one more hadith about dreams,

**It was narrated from Ibn ‘Abbaas that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:"Whoever tells of a dream that he did not see will be commanded [on the Day of Resurrection] to tie two grains of barley together, but he will never be able to do it." (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 6635)**

may Allah the mighty and sublime guide you to the straight path.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Cause and purpose must not be the same.

Comment: @Medi1Saif maybe my usage of words caused the confusion about cause and purpose, the answer is in the viewpoint of purpose. jazaakallah khairan for the clarity.

Comment: Alaikum Salam was Ratmatullahi wa barakatuh brother. Thank you for kindly taking the time to reply and your answer. Abdul Latif